# Implementing a custom TypeConverter

Tags: c#, .net, system.componentmodel, typedescriptor

I have a really simple scenario where I just want to extend the functionality of the `System.ComponentModel.BooleanConverter` so that it will allow multiple options rather than just `true` and `false`.

So for example values like `yes`, `1`, `on` etc. are the same as `true`.

I tried overriding the `GetStandardValues()` methods to do a quick test, my assumption being that if I returned a collection of all my specific values that a call to `IsValid(string)` should return `true` if I pass in one of my defined values but this does not appear to be the case. Do I have to implement/override a whole bunch of crap to do this?

I'm wondering if it's worth it since all I really need is the `IsValid()` functionality. Or perhaps there is a better option than using `TypeDescriptors` in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you "only need `IsValid` functionality" then it should be enough to override just it. However, in practice [`CanConvertFrom(Type)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92580th5.aspx) is actually the method you should override if you're just looking to test if type can be converted. This method is used by some infrastructure classes, and just overriding `IsValid` might not be enough in that case.

For boolean converter you should also override [`ConvertFrom(object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef83h055.aspx), and just return `null` if you're not going to use the value. Otherwise, calling `IsValid` (which in turn calls `CanConvertFrom`) could fail.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nikola. After some testing I discovered that this is not a good way to solve my issue. Using IsValid to test string values like this is not a good design decision on my part. What happens behind the scenes is that .NET throws a System.FormatException if it fails the check so that's a lot of extra stack overhead when using this heavily.